# Two pass high quality theora/vorbis ffmpeg encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, ogg, ogg-theora

I want to achieve the same video encoding that I had with ffmpeg2theora with standard ffmpeg, this is because i need the flexibility ffmpeg has to make the container mkv, with subtitles other than srt.

In ffmpeg2theora i have the following command that output a very high quality and very small filesize file:

```
$ ffmpeg2theora --videobitrate 2000 --two-pass --first-pass firstpass --speedlevel 0 --width 640 --height 360 --resize-method lanczos --noaudio input.mkv
$ ffmpeg2theora --videobitrate 2000 --two-pass --second-pass firstpass --speedlevel 0 --width 640 --height 360 --resize-method lanczos --noaudio input.mkv --output output.ogv
```

Being the most interesting options here i think (From ffmpeg2theora manual page):

```
--two-pass
--first-pass <filename>
--second-pass <filename> 
--speedlevel
    encoding is faster with higher values the cost is quality and bandwidth (default 1)
```

But i can only found a simple way to encode theora/vorbis in standard ffmpeg (from: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -codec:v libtheora -qscale:v 7 -codec:a libvorbis -qscale:a 5 output.ogv
```

That produces a very bad quality output even in the best quality setting (10)

How can I do a 2 pass 'high quality'/'not so big filesize' theora/vorbis in plain ffmpeg?

Comment: ```qscale``` is a quantizer (beware: not that common in more modern codecs -> constant-rate-factor), meaning: highest-quality = smaller values! [The docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-23) seem to indicate there is some approximate inverse / [global_quality](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-23), probably because theora did it different. The link also indicates pass1 and pass 2 is supported, so take the classic [h264 example](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass) and try it with theora!

Comment: I have to ask...why Theora? It's old and not as efficient as newer choices such as VP9/VP8.

Comment: I made several attemps with vp9, but the quality of the picture under cetain conditions in videos was worse than my attemps with theora, even trying the highest quality settings in vp9 that were like 10 times more slower than theora resulted in these conditions with worse quality than theora, videos with complex patterns with horizontally scrolling vertical lines and the like, resulting in artifacts with VP9